# in c language ask the user for his name , if the name is in the DB ,print “welcome (name)”, if not print “name isn't in DB

Tags: arrays, c, string, if-statement

I wrote the code below in c language but the problem is that (if) always gives me false

```
char DB[][50]={"ahmed alla","Shady Ibrahim","Sara Sedky","Mohamed Ezz"};
    char name[50];
    fgets(name,50,stdin);
    int flag=1;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        if(name==DB[i])
        {
            flag=0;
            printf("welcome %s \n",name);
        }
    }
    if(flag)
    {
        printf("sorry your name is not in the DB!");
    }
```

it always prints "sorry your name is not in the DB!" whatever the name is

Comment: I think you should use strcmp instead of ==. And fgets always adds a new line after the entered string.

Comment: `if(name==DB[i])` --> `if (strcmp(name, DB[i]) == 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Two points:

First,
`fgets()` consider newline character as a valid character and include it in the string copied to buffer passed. Make sure to remove trailing newline character from `name` buffer. After `fgets()`, may you can do

```
name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
```

[Documentation on strcspn](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn).

Second, in `C`, use `strcmp()` to compare two string

```
if (strcmp (name, DB[I]) == 0) {
  // strings are same
```

[Documentation on strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)